# How to disable "Open in external viewer" and "Download" menu automatically showed from webview when a pdf is loaded?

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf, webview

I want disable the "open" end "download" functionality from this menu in cocoa WebView, or alternatively disable entire menu.

[image]
<sub>(source: [federicocappelli.net](http://www.federicocappelli.net/filehost/webview_menu.png))</sub>

Comment: Have you considered using `PDFView` instead of `WebView`?

Comment: I have no choice, i must use a webview, that works very well, the only problem is this menu.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slim chance that if you implement a WebUIDelegate whose implementation of `webView:contextMenuItemsForElement:defaultMenuItems:` filters out `WebMenuItemTagOpenWithDefaultApplication` and `WebMenuItemTagDownloadImageToDisk` then that would prevent the web view from showing those two options in the overlay.

Otherwise, you can try subclassing `WebView` and overriding `-mouseMoved:` to swallow those events.  That might interfere with normal functioning, though.

Or maybe you can override `-addTrackingArea:` to prevent the adding of whatever tracking area is used to show the overlay.

Comment: I did a test, contextMenuItemsForElement is called only at right click on the webview, but this menu appear without any click, only moving mouse in the bottom part of the webview.  I can't subclassing WebView :(